# Create new files from upload

Tags: python, linux, django, permissions, subprocess

I'm stuck with a little problem:

I have a website to manage videofiles for different users. Each user can upload videos to a personal folder which I don't want to change because I don't want to mix up files from different users. After uploading the video file I call a `subprocess` which should create a thumbnail. The subprocess fails because of an error in `ffmpeg`, seeming to be related to missing writing permissions. The uploaded file and the containing folder belong to www-data.

The code:

```
command = ("ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i %s -dframes 1 %s -y" % (video_path, image_path)).split()
subprocess.call(command)
```

FFMPEG seems to be run as a different user because it only works if the target-folder has 777-permissions. Otherwise it fails with this message:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error occurred
Usually that means that input file is truncated and/or corrupted.
```

If I `touch` the image-file instead of creating it via ffmpeg it doesn't matter if the folder has 775 or 777. The resulting file then also belongs to www-data, which means that the subprocess itself is run as www-data, doesn't it?

I thought about creating a subfolder which has 777-permissions but I don't like it for two reasons: This folder had to be created dynamically because I want to be able to create new users (and resulting new subfolders in my uploads-folder). 777-permissions are no nice solution anyway.

Do you have any suggestions what I have to change so ffmpeg can write to the folder without opening security leaks and without having to touch anything when creating a new user/folder?

Comment: good question, I have exactly the same problem

Comment: Sub process runs with which user and how do you change that?

Comment: Actually I don't change the user and it seems not to be a permission-problem at all. It could as well be related to the way I call the subprocess.

Comment: From your post as it is now, I cant judge what was wrong, and in what way. Is your snippet working or not? What changes lead to working/non-working state change?

Comment: You are right, it wasn't clear any more. I edited it too often because I thought the problem was somewhere else... Now it should be understandable again.

Comment: It may not be problem with permissions. Can you play the video file uploaded? Also, try running the same `ffmpeg` command from command line and as `www-data` user.

Comment: I can play the file and I can run the command if the target folder has 777-permissions. If I run the command as www-data it is working as well although it shows the same error (file created but with error message). Another strange thing is that I am able to create a new file with `touch` from my django-code but not with `ffmpeg`...

Comment: It really wasn't a problem with permissions but with error handling, `-dframes` and `-vframes` (see answer below)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

It was not a permission-problem but something strange in error handling: If the code is run from the webserver the resulting image-file is dismissed when the error occurs. If it is run from command line the resulting file remains in the folder.

So basically I changed my command that no error message appears any more by using `-vframes` instead of `-dframes` (which only worked fine in windows):

```
command = ("ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i %s -vframes 1 %s -y" % (video_path, image_path)).split()
```

Comment: lol, I posted it as answer, but deleted, as `dframes` is synonim for `vframes` for newer versions of ffmpeg (1.9 and later). Undeleted :)

Comment: @boefri working/not working with what version of ffmpeg? see ref to changelog in my answer (1.9 is a typo, should be 0.9)

Comment: It's version 0.5.10 from the debian-squeeze-sources. *Perhaps* I should update it... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying `-vframes 1` as described [here](http://lzone.de/ffmpeg_av_interleaved_write_frame_io_error)

However, for [ffmpeg 0.9 and later](https://raw.github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/Changelog) both `dframes` and `vframes` are aliases for `frames`, so if you use newer version of ffmpeg, problem is somewhere in other place.

Answer (score 1):

You could run conversion process asynchronously with [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Your worker process might be invoked with required permissions, and apache just needs permissions to access communication channel, such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for example

Comment: Don't you think it's a little overkill?